# Htaccess issue, RewriteRule ignores other characters at the end of first parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So I have this rule:

```
RewriteRule page other-page.php
```

So now when I go to `mysite.php/page` it goes to `other-page.php` which is is fine. But when I go, for example, to:

```
mysite.php/pages
```

or:

```
mysite.php/pagedfkjsdf
```

or anything that starts with `/page` it goes to `other-page.php`. It should show a 404 error instead. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your rule will redirect anything with `page` anywhere in the URI. What you need to do is change it so it only matches `/page`. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page$ other-page.php
```

The `^` matches the start of the string, the `$` matches the end.

I assume you're doing this in your `.htaccess` file or in a `<Directory>` block. If not the rule will need updating to:

```
RewriteRule ^/page$ /other-page.php
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, yes I'll fix my code above to avoid misunderstanding for future visitors!

Comment: Sorry I have another problem, when I go to mysite.com/page it works but when I go to mysite.com/page/ it doesn't any ideas?

Comment: Yes just change the regex to `^page/?$` so it has an optional slash at the end.

Comment: Just a thought, but as an alternative to the optional slash, it's probably better to only have one working URL for your page, and redirect the other to it. So you could add this rule instead `RewriteRule ^page/$ /page [L,R=301]`